# Handling Bel constraint conflict critical error on Vivado

Tags: fpga, hardware, vivado

I am trying to place 20 Ring oscillators on the FPGA.

I have followed the user constraints Xilinx guide on XDC macro creation and the video - ([XDC Macro][1] ). I tried initially with placing 5 Ring oscillators and it worked and didn't throw any warnings. So, I tried this with 20 Ring oscillators and wanted to place them in a way so that I could create a square shape for uniform distribution.  When I tried running the implementation, I faced the following critical warnings (18 of them in total) :

```
**[Vivado 12-2285] Cannot set LOC property of instance 'u3/w1_inferred_i_1'... Instance u3/w1_inferred_i_1 can not be placed in D6LUT of site SLICE_X12Y244 because the bel is occupied by u2/w1_inferred_i_1. This could be caused by bel constraint conflict**

**[Vivado 12-2285] Cannot set LOC property of instance 'u4/w1_inferred_i_1'... Instance u4/w1_inferred_i_1 can not be placed in D6LUT of site SLICE_X12Y244 because the bel is occupied by u2/w1_inferred_i_1. This could be caused by bel constraint conflict**
```

others are similar to the above ones

---

I am giving my constraints file as this might make things clear for understanding and helping me out.

```
# User Generated physical constraints 

create_macro macro1
update_macro [get_macros macro1] -rlocs {w1_inferred_i_1 X0Y151 w2_inferred_i_1 X0Y150 w3_inferred_i_1 X0Y150 w4_inferred_i_1 X0Y150 w5_inferred_i_1 X0Y151 w6_inferred_i_1 X0Y151 w7_inferred_i_1 X0Y151 w8_inferred_i_1 X0Y152 w9_inferred_i_1 X0Y152 w10_inferred_i_1 X0Y152 w11_inferred_i_1 X0Y152 w12_inferred_i_1 X0Y153 w13_inferred_i_1 X0Y153 w15_inferred_i_1 X0Y153}
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells w1_inferred_i_1]
set_property LOC SLICE_X12Y244 [get_cells w1_inferred_i_1]

**ro_placement.xdc :**

    set_property BEL A6LUT [get_cells u5/w1_inferred_i_1__3]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y221 [get_cells u5/w1_inferred_i_1__3]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u5/w2_inferred_i_1__3]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y220 [get_cells u5/w2_inferred_i_1__3]
set_property BEL C5LUT [get_cells u5/w3_inferred_i_1__3]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y220 [get_cells u5/w3_inferred_i_1__3]
set_property BEL B6LUT [get_cells u5/w4_inferred_i_1__3]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y220 [get_cells u5/w4_inferred_i_1__3]
set_property BEL A6LUT [get_cells u5/w5_inferred_i_1__3]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y220 [get_cells u5/w5_inferred_i_1__3]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u5/w6_inferred_i_1__3]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y219 [get_cells u5/w6_inferred_i_1__3]
set_property BEL C6LUT [get_cells u5/w7_inferred_i_1__3]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y219 [get_cells u5/w7_inferred_i_1__3]
set_property BEL B6LUT [get_cells u5/w8_inferred_i_1__3]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y219 [get_cells u5/w8_inferred_i_1__3]
set_property BEL A6LUT [get_cells u5/w9_inferred_i_1__3]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y219 [get_cells u5/w9_inferred_i_1__3]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u5/w10_inferred_i_1__3]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y218 [get_cells u5/w10_inferred_i_1__3]
set_property BEL C6LUT [get_cells u5/w11_inferred_i_1__3]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y218 [get_cells u5/w11_inferred_i_1__3]
set_property BEL B6LUT [get_cells u5/w12_inferred_i_1__3]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y218 [get_cells u5/w12_inferred_i_1__3]
set_property BEL A6LUT [get_cells u5/w13_inferred_i_1__3]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y218 [get_cells u5/w13_inferred_i_1__3]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u5/w15_inferred_i_1__3]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y217 [get_cells u5/w15_inferred_i_1__3]
set_property BEL B6LUT [get_cells u6/w1_inferred_i_1__4]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y217 [get_cells u6/w1_inferred_i_1__4]
set_property BEL A6LUT [get_cells u6/w2_inferred_i_1__4]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y217 [get_cells u6/w2_inferred_i_1__4]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u6/w3_inferred_i_1__4]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y216 [get_cells u6/w3_inferred_i_1__4]
set_property BEL C6LUT [get_cells u6/w4_inferred_i_1__4]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y216 [get_cells u6/w4_inferred_i_1__4]
set_property BEL B6LUT [get_cells u6/w5_inferred_i_1__4]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y216 [get_cells u6/w5_inferred_i_1__4]
set_property BEL A6LUT [get_cells u6/w6_inferred_i_1__4]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y216 [get_cells u6/w6_inferred_i_1__4]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u6/w7_inferred_i_1__4]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y215 [get_cells u6/w7_inferred_i_1__4]
set_property BEL C6LUT [get_cells u6/w8_inferred_i_1__4]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y215 [get_cells u6/w8_inferred_i_1__4]
set_property BEL B6LUT [get_cells u6/w9_inferred_i_1__4]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y215 [get_cells u6/w9_inferred_i_1__4]
set_property BEL A6LUT [get_cells u6/w10_inferred_i_1__4]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y215 [get_cells u6/w10_inferred_i_1__4]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u6/w11_inferred_i_1__4]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y214 [get_cells u6/w11_inferred_i_1__4]
set_property BEL C6LUT [get_cells u6/w12_inferred_i_1__4]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y214 [get_cells u6/w12_inferred_i_1__4]
set_property BEL B6LUT [get_cells u6/w13_inferred_i_1__4]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y214 [get_cells u6/w13_inferred_i_1__4]
set_property BEL A6LUT [get_cells u6/w15_inferred_i_1__4]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y214 [get_cells u6/w15_inferred_i_1__4]
set_property BEL A6LUT [get_cells u7/w2_inferred_i_1__5]
set_property LOC SLICE_X15Y214 [get_cells u7/w2_inferred_i_1__5]
set_property BEL A6LUT [get_cells u7/w3_inferred_i_1__5]
set_property LOC SLICE_X16Y214 [get_cells u7/w3_inferred_i_1__5]
set_property BEL A5LUT [get_cells u7/w1_inferred_i_1__5]
set_property LOC SLICE_X14Y214 [get_cells u7/w1_inferred_i_1__5]
set_property BEL A5LUT [get_cells u7/w4_inferred_i_1__5]
set_property LOC SLICE_X17Y214 [get_cells u7/w4_inferred_i_1__5]
set_property BEL A5LUT [get_cells u7/w5_inferred_i_1__5]
set_property LOC SLICE_X18Y214 [get_cells u7/w5_inferred_i_1__5]
set_property BEL A5LUT [get_cells u7/w6_inferred_i_1__5]
set_property LOC SLICE_X19Y214 [get_cells u7/w6_inferred_i_1__5]
set_property BEL A6LUT [get_cells u7/w7_inferred_i_1__5]
set_property LOC SLICE_X20Y214 [get_cells u7/w7_inferred_i_1__5]
set_property BEL A5LUT [get_cells u7/w8_inferred_i_1__5]
set_property LOC SLICE_X21Y214 [get_cells u7/w8_inferred_i_1__5]
set_property BEL A6LUT [get_cells u7/w9_inferred_i_1__5]
set_property LOC SLICE_X22Y214 [get_cells u7/w9_inferred_i_1__5]
set_property BEL A6LUT [get_cells u7/w10_inferred_i_1__5]
set_property LOC SLICE_X23Y214 [get_cells u7/w10_inferred_i_1__5]
set_property BEL A6LUT [get_cells u7/w11_inferred_i_1__5]
set_property LOC SLICE_X24Y214 [get_cells u7/w11_inferred_i_1__5]
set_property BEL A5LUT [get_cells u7/w12_inferred_i_1__5]
set_property LOC SLICE_X25Y214 [get_cells u7/w12_inferred_i_1__5]
set_property BEL A5LUT [get_cells u7/w13_inferred_i_1__5]
set_property LOC SLICE_X26Y214 [get_cells u7/w13_inferred_i_1__5]
set_property BEL A6LUT [get_cells u7/w15_inferred_i_1__5]
set_property LOC SLICE_X27Y214 [get_cells u7/w15_inferred_i_1__5]
set_property BEL A5LUT [get_cells u8/w1_inferred_i_1__6]
set_property LOC SLICE_X28Y214 [get_cells u8/w1_inferred_i_1__6]
set_property BEL A6LUT [get_cells u8/w2_inferred_i_1__6]
set_property LOC SLICE_X29Y214 [get_cells u8/w2_inferred_i_1__6]
set_property BEL A5LUT [get_cells u8/w3_inferred_i_1__6]
set_property LOC SLICE_X30Y214 [get_cells u8/w3_inferred_i_1__6]
set_property BEL A5LUT [get_cells u8/w4_inferred_i_1__6]
set_property LOC SLICE_X31Y214 [get_cells u8/w4_inferred_i_1__6]
set_property BEL A6LUT [get_cells u8/w5_inferred_i_1__6]
set_property LOC SLICE_X32Y214 [get_cells u8/w5_inferred_i_1__6]
set_property BEL A5LUT [get_cells u8/w6_inferred_i_1__6]
set_property LOC SLICE_X33Y214 [get_cells u8/w6_inferred_i_1__6]
set_property BEL A5LUT [get_cells u8/w7_inferred_i_1__6]
set_property LOC SLICE_X34Y214 [get_cells u8/w7_inferred_i_1__6]
set_property BEL A6LUT [get_cells u8/w8_inferred_i_1__6]
set_property LOC SLICE_X35Y214 [get_cells u8/w8_inferred_i_1__6]
set_property BEL A6LUT [get_cells u8/w9_inferred_i_1__6]
set_property LOC SLICE_X42Y214 [get_cells u8/w9_inferred_i_1__6]
set_property BEL A6LUT [get_cells u8/w10_inferred_i_1__6]
set_property LOC SLICE_X43Y214 [get_cells u8/w10_inferred_i_1__6]
set_property BEL A6LUT [get_cells u8/w11_inferred_i_1__6]
set_property LOC SLICE_X44Y214 [get_cells u8/w11_inferred_i_1__6]
set_property BEL A5LUT [get_cells u8/w12_inferred_i_1__6]
set_property LOC SLICE_X45Y214 [get_cells u8/w12_inferred_i_1__6]
set_property BEL A6LUT [get_cells u8/w13_inferred_i_1__6]
set_property LOC SLICE_X46Y214 [get_cells u8/w13_inferred_i_1__6]
set_property BEL A6LUT [get_cells u8/w15_inferred_i_1__6]
set_property LOC SLICE_X47Y214 [get_cells u8/w15_inferred_i_1__6]
set_property BEL A5LUT [get_cells u10/w1_inferred_i_1__8]
set_property LOC SLICE_X48Y214 [get_cells u10/w1_inferred_i_1__8]
set_property BEL A5LUT [get_cells u10/w2_inferred_i_1__8]
set_property LOC SLICE_X49Y214 [get_cells u10/w2_inferred_i_1__8]
set_property BEL A5LUT [get_cells u10/w3_inferred_i_1__8]
set_property LOC SLICE_X50Y214 [get_cells u10/w3_inferred_i_1__8]
set_property BEL A5LUT [get_cells u10/w4_inferred_i_1__8]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y214 [get_cells u10/w4_inferred_i_1__8]
set_property BEL B6LUT [get_cells u10/w5_inferred_i_1__8]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y214 [get_cells u10/w5_inferred_i_1__8]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u10/w6_inferred_i_1__8]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y214 [get_cells u10/w6_inferred_i_1__8]
set_property BEL A6LUT [get_cells u10/w7_inferred_i_1__8]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y215 [get_cells u10/w7_inferred_i_1__8]
set_property BEL C6LUT [get_cells u10/w8_inferred_i_1__8]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y215 [get_cells u10/w8_inferred_i_1__8]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u10/w9_inferred_i_1__8]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y215 [get_cells u10/w9_inferred_i_1__8]
set_property BEL A6LUT [get_cells u10/w10_inferred_i_1__8]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y216 [get_cells u10/w10_inferred_i_1__8]
set_property BEL B6LUT [get_cells u10/w11_inferred_i_1__8]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y216 [get_cells u10/w11_inferred_i_1__8]
set_property BEL C6LUT [get_cells u10/w12_inferred_i_1__8]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y216 [get_cells u10/w12_inferred_i_1__8]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u10/w13_inferred_i_1__8]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y216 [get_cells u10/w13_inferred_i_1__8]
set_property BEL A6LUT [get_cells u10/w15_inferred_i_1__8]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y217 [get_cells u10/w15_inferred_i_1__8]
set_property BEL B6LUT [get_cells u11/w1_inferred_i_1__9]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y217 [get_cells u11/w1_inferred_i_1__9]
set_property BEL C6LUT [get_cells u11/w2_inferred_i_1__9]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y217 [get_cells u11/w2_inferred_i_1__9]
set_property BEL D5LUT [get_cells u11/w3_inferred_i_1__9]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y217 [get_cells u11/w3_inferred_i_1__9]
set_property BEL A6LUT [get_cells u11/w4_inferred_i_1__9]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y218 [get_cells u11/w4_inferred_i_1__9]
set_property BEL B6LUT [get_cells u11/w5_inferred_i_1__9]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y218 [get_cells u11/w5_inferred_i_1__9]
set_property BEL C6LUT [get_cells u11/w6_inferred_i_1__9]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y218 [get_cells u11/w6_inferred_i_1__9]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u11/w7_inferred_i_1__9]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y218 [get_cells u11/w7_inferred_i_1__9]
set_property BEL A6LUT [get_cells u11/w8_inferred_i_1__9]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y219 [get_cells u11/w8_inferred_i_1__9]
set_property BEL C6LUT [get_cells u11/w9_inferred_i_1__9]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y219 [get_cells u11/w9_inferred_i_1__9]
set_property BEL D5LUT [get_cells u11/w10_inferred_i_1__9]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y219 [get_cells u11/w10_inferred_i_1__9]
set_property BEL A6LUT [get_cells u11/w11_inferred_i_1__9]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y220 [get_cells u11/w11_inferred_i_1__9]
set_property BEL B6LUT [get_cells u11/w12_inferred_i_1__9]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y220 [get_cells u11/w12_inferred_i_1__9]
set_property BEL C6LUT [get_cells u11/w13_inferred_i_1__9]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y220 [get_cells u11/w13_inferred_i_1__9]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u11/w15_inferred_i_1__9]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y220 [get_cells u11/w15_inferred_i_1__9]
set_property BEL A6LUT [get_cells u12/w1_inferred_i_1__10]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y221 [get_cells u12/w1_inferred_i_1__10]
set_property BEL B6LUT [get_cells u12/w2_inferred_i_1__10]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y221 [get_cells u12/w2_inferred_i_1__10]
set_property BEL C6LUT [get_cells u12/w3_inferred_i_1__10]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y221 [get_cells u12/w3_inferred_i_1__10]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u12/w4_inferred_i_1__10]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y221 [get_cells u12/w4_inferred_i_1__10]
set_property BEL A6LUT [get_cells u12/w5_inferred_i_1__10]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y222 [get_cells u12/w5_inferred_i_1__10]
set_property BEL B6LUT [get_cells u12/w6_inferred_i_1__10]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y222 [get_cells u12/w6_inferred_i_1__10]
set_property BEL C6LUT [get_cells u12/w7_inferred_i_1__10]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y222 [get_cells u12/w7_inferred_i_1__10]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u12/w8_inferred_i_1__10]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y222 [get_cells u12/w8_inferred_i_1__10]
set_property BEL A6LUT [get_cells u12/w9_inferred_i_1__10]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y223 [get_cells u12/w9_inferred_i_1__10]
set_property BEL B6LUT [get_cells u12/w10_inferred_i_1__10]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y223 [get_cells u12/w10_inferred_i_1__10]
set_property BEL C6LUT [get_cells u12/w11_inferred_i_1__10]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y223 [get_cells u12/w11_inferred_i_1__10]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u12/w12_inferred_i_1__10]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y223 [get_cells u12/w12_inferred_i_1__10]
set_property BEL A6LUT [get_cells u12/w13_inferred_i_1__10]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y224 [get_cells u12/w13_inferred_i_1__10]
set_property BEL B6LUT [get_cells u12/w15_inferred_i_1__10]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y224 [get_cells u12/w15_inferred_i_1__10]
set_property BEL A6LUT [get_cells u13/w1_inferred_i_1__11]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y228 [get_cells u13/w1_inferred_i_1__11]
set_property BEL B6LUT [get_cells u13/w2_inferred_i_1__11]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y228 [get_cells u13/w2_inferred_i_1__11]
set_property BEL C6LUT [get_cells u13/w3_inferred_i_1__11]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y228 [get_cells u13/w3_inferred_i_1__11]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u13/w4_inferred_i_1__11]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y228 [get_cells u13/w4_inferred_i_1__11]
set_property BEL A6LUT [get_cells u13/w5_inferred_i_1__11]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y229 [get_cells u13/w5_inferred_i_1__11]
set_property BEL B6LUT [get_cells u13/w6_inferred_i_1__11]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y229 [get_cells u13/w6_inferred_i_1__11]
set_property BEL C6LUT [get_cells u13/w7_inferred_i_1__11]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y229 [get_cells u13/w7_inferred_i_1__11]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u13/w8_inferred_i_1__11]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y229 [get_cells u13/w8_inferred_i_1__11]
set_property BEL A6LUT [get_cells u13/w9_inferred_i_1__11]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y230 [get_cells u13/w9_inferred_i_1__11]
set_property BEL B6LUT [get_cells u13/w10_inferred_i_1__11]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y230 [get_cells u13/w10_inferred_i_1__11]
set_property BEL C6LUT [get_cells u13/w11_inferred_i_1__11]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y230 [get_cells u13/w11_inferred_i_1__11]
set_property BEL A6LUT [get_cells u13/w12_inferred_i_1__11]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y231 [get_cells u13/w12_inferred_i_1__11]
set_property BEL B6LUT [get_cells u13/w13_inferred_i_1__11]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y231 [get_cells u13/w13_inferred_i_1__11]
set_property BEL C5LUT [get_cells u13/w15_inferred_i_1__11]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y231 [get_cells u13/w15_inferred_i_1__11]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u14/w1_inferred_i_1__12]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y231 [get_cells u14/w1_inferred_i_1__12]
set_property BEL A6LUT [get_cells u14/w2_inferred_i_1__12]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y232 [get_cells u14/w2_inferred_i_1__12]
set_property BEL B6LUT [get_cells u14/w3_inferred_i_1__12]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y232 [get_cells u14/w3_inferred_i_1__12]
set_property BEL C6LUT [get_cells u14/w4_inferred_i_1__12]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y232 [get_cells u14/w4_inferred_i_1__12]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u14/w5_inferred_i_1__12]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y232 [get_cells u14/w5_inferred_i_1__12]
set_property BEL A6LUT [get_cells u14/w6_inferred_i_1__12]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y233 [get_cells u14/w6_inferred_i_1__12]
set_property BEL B6LUT [get_cells u14/w7_inferred_i_1__12]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y233 [get_cells u14/w7_inferred_i_1__12]
set_property BEL C6LUT [get_cells u14/w8_inferred_i_1__12]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y233 [get_cells u14/w8_inferred_i_1__12]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u14/w9_inferred_i_1__12]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y233 [get_cells u14/w9_inferred_i_1__12]
set_property BEL A6LUT [get_cells u14/w10_inferred_i_1__12]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y234 [get_cells u14/w10_inferred_i_1__12]
set_property BEL B6LUT [get_cells u14/w11_inferred_i_1__12]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y234 [get_cells u14/w11_inferred_i_1__12]
set_property BEL C6LUT [get_cells u14/w12_inferred_i_1__12]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y234 [get_cells u14/w12_inferred_i_1__12]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u14/w13_inferred_i_1__12]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y234 [get_cells u14/w13_inferred_i_1__12]
set_property BEL B6LUT [get_cells u14/w15_inferred_i_1__12]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y235 [get_cells u14/w15_inferred_i_1__12]
set_property BEL C6LUT [get_cells u15/w1_inferred_i_1__13]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y235 [get_cells u15/w1_inferred_i_1__13]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u15/w2_inferred_i_1__13]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y235 [get_cells u15/w2_inferred_i_1__13]
set_property BEL A6LUT [get_cells u15/w3_inferred_i_1__13]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y236 [get_cells u15/w3_inferred_i_1__13]
set_property BEL B6LUT [get_cells u15/w4_inferred_i_1__13]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y236 [get_cells u15/w4_inferred_i_1__13]
set_property BEL C6LUT [get_cells u15/w5_inferred_i_1__13]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y236 [get_cells u15/w5_inferred_i_1__13]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u15/w6_inferred_i_1__13]
set_property LOC SLICE_X51Y236 [get_cells u15/w6_inferred_i_1__13]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u15/w7_inferred_i_1__13]
set_property LOC SLICE_X50Y236 [get_cells u15/w7_inferred_i_1__13]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u15/w8_inferred_i_1__13]
set_property LOC SLICE_X49Y236 [get_cells u15/w8_inferred_i_1__13]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u15/w9_inferred_i_1__13]
set_property LOC SLICE_X48Y236 [get_cells u15/w9_inferred_i_1__13]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u15/w10_inferred_i_1__13]
set_property LOC SLICE_X47Y236 [get_cells u15/w10_inferred_i_1__13]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u15/w11_inferred_i_1__13]
set_property LOC SLICE_X46Y236 [get_cells u15/w11_inferred_i_1__13]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u15/w13_inferred_i_1__13]
set_property LOC SLICE_X45Y236 [get_cells u15/w13_inferred_i_1__13]
set_property BEL D5LUT [get_cells u15/w15_inferred_i_1__13]
set_property LOC SLICE_X44Y236 [get_cells u15/w15_inferred_i_1__13]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u16/w1_inferred_i_1__14]
set_property LOC SLICE_X43Y236 [get_cells u16/w1_inferred_i_1__14]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u16/w2_inferred_i_1__14]
set_property LOC SLICE_X42Y236 [get_cells u16/w2_inferred_i_1__14]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u16/w3_inferred_i_1__14]
set_property LOC SLICE_X41Y236 [get_cells u16/w3_inferred_i_1__14]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u16/w4_inferred_i_1__14]
set_property LOC SLICE_X40Y236 [get_cells u16/w4_inferred_i_1__14]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u16/w5_inferred_i_1__14]
set_property LOC SLICE_X39Y236 [get_cells u16/w5_inferred_i_1__14]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u16/w6_inferred_i_1__14]
set_property LOC SLICE_X38Y236 [get_cells u16/w6_inferred_i_1__14]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u16/w7_inferred_i_1__14]
set_property LOC SLICE_X37Y236 [get_cells u16/w7_inferred_i_1__14]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u16/w8_inferred_i_1__14]
set_property LOC SLICE_X36Y236 [get_cells u16/w8_inferred_i_1__14]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u16/w9_inferred_i_1__14]
set_property LOC SLICE_X35Y236 [get_cells u16/w9_inferred_i_1__14]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u16/w10_inferred_i_1__14]
set_property LOC SLICE_X34Y236 [get_cells u16/w10_inferred_i_1__14]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u16/w11_inferred_i_1__14]
set_property LOC SLICE_X33Y236 [get_cells u16/w11_inferred_i_1__14]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u16/w12_inferred_i_1__14]
set_property LOC SLICE_X32Y236 [get_cells u16/w12_inferred_i_1__14]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u16/w13_inferred_i_1__14]
set_property LOC SLICE_X31Y236 [get_cells u16/w13_inferred_i_1__14]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u16/w15_inferred_i_1__14]
set_property LOC SLICE_X30Y236 [get_cells u16/w15_inferred_i_1__14]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u17/w1_inferred_i_1__15]
set_property LOC SLICE_X29Y236 [get_cells u17/w1_inferred_i_1__15]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u17/w2_inferred_i_1__15]
set_property LOC SLICE_X28Y236 [get_cells u17/w2_inferred_i_1__15]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u17/w3_inferred_i_1__15]
set_property LOC SLICE_X27Y236 [get_cells u17/w3_inferred_i_1__15]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u17/w4_inferred_i_1__15]
set_property LOC SLICE_X26Y236 [get_cells u17/w4_inferred_i_1__15]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u17/w5_inferred_i_1__15]
set_property LOC SLICE_X25Y236 [get_cells u17/w5_inferred_i_1__15]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u17/w6_inferred_i_1__15]
set_property LOC SLICE_X24Y236 [get_cells u17/w6_inferred_i_1__15]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u17/w7_inferred_i_1__15]
set_property LOC SLICE_X23Y236 [get_cells u17/w7_inferred_i_1__15]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u17/w8_inferred_i_1__15]
set_property LOC SLICE_X22Y236 [get_cells u17/w8_inferred_i_1__15]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u17/w9_inferred_i_1__15]
set_property LOC SLICE_X21Y236 [get_cells u17/w9_inferred_i_1__15]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u17/w10_inferred_i_1__15]
set_property LOC SLICE_X20Y236 [get_cells u17/w10_inferred_i_1__15]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u17/w11_inferred_i_1__15]
set_property LOC SLICE_X19Y236 [get_cells u17/w11_inferred_i_1__15]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u17/w12_inferred_i_1__15]
set_property LOC SLICE_X18Y236 [get_cells u17/w12_inferred_i_1__15]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u17/w13_inferred_i_1__15]
set_property LOC SLICE_X17Y236 [get_cells u17/w13_inferred_i_1__15]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u17/w15_inferred_i_1__15]
set_property LOC SLICE_X16Y236 [get_cells u17/w15_inferred_i_1__15]
set_property BEL B6LUT [get_cells u4/w15_inferred_i_1__2]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y221 [get_cells u4/w15_inferred_i_1__2]
set_property BEL C6LUT [get_cells u4/w13_inferred_i_1__2]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y221 [get_cells u4/w13_inferred_i_1__2]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u4/w12_inferred_i_1__2]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y221 [get_cells u4/w12_inferred_i_1__2]
set_property BEL A6LUT [get_cells u4/w11_inferred_i_1__2]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y222 [get_cells u4/w11_inferred_i_1__2]
set_property BEL B6LUT [get_cells u4/w10_inferred_i_1__2]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y222 [get_cells u4/w10_inferred_i_1__2]
set_property BEL C6LUT [get_cells u4/w9_inferred_i_1__2]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y222 [get_cells u4/w9_inferred_i_1__2]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u4/w8_inferred_i_1__2]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y222 [get_cells u4/w8_inferred_i_1__2]
set_property BEL A6LUT [get_cells u4/w7_inferred_i_1__2]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y223 [get_cells u4/w7_inferred_i_1__2]
set_property BEL B6LUT [get_cells u4/w6_inferred_i_1__2]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y223 [get_cells u4/w6_inferred_i_1__2]
set_property BEL C6LUT [get_cells u4/w5_inferred_i_1__2]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y223 [get_cells u4/w5_inferred_i_1__2]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u4/w4_inferred_i_1__2]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y223 [get_cells u4/w4_inferred_i_1__2]
set_property BEL A6LUT [get_cells u4/w3_inferred_i_1__2]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y224 [get_cells u4/w3_inferred_i_1__2]
set_property BEL B6LUT [get_cells u4/w2_inferred_i_1__2]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y224 [get_cells u4/w2_inferred_i_1__2]
set_property BEL C6LUT [get_cells u4/w1_inferred_i_1__2]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y224 [get_cells u4/w1_inferred_i_1__2]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u3/w15_inferred_i_1__1]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y224 [get_cells u3/w15_inferred_i_1__1]
set_property BEL A6LUT [get_cells u3/w13_inferred_i_1__1]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y225 [get_cells u3/w13_inferred_i_1__1]
set_property BEL B6LUT [get_cells u3/w12_inferred_i_1__1]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y225 [get_cells u3/w12_inferred_i_1__1]
set_property BEL C6LUT [get_cells u3/w11_inferred_i_1__1]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y225 [get_cells u3/w11_inferred_i_1__1]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u3/w10_inferred_i_1__1]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y225 [get_cells u3/w10_inferred_i_1__1]
set_property BEL A6LUT [get_cells u3/w9_inferred_i_1__1]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y226 [get_cells u3/w9_inferred_i_1__1]
set_property BEL B6LUT [get_cells u3/w8_inferred_i_1__1]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y226 [get_cells u3/w8_inferred_i_1__1]
set_property BEL C5LUT [get_cells u3/w7_inferred_i_1__1]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y226 [get_cells u3/w7_inferred_i_1__1]
set_property BEL D5LUT [get_cells u3/w6_inferred_i_1__1]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y226 [get_cells u3/w6_inferred_i_1__1]
set_property BEL A6LUT [get_cells u3/w5_inferred_i_1__1]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y227 [get_cells u3/w5_inferred_i_1__1]
set_property BEL B5LUT [get_cells u3/w4_inferred_i_1__1]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y227 [get_cells u3/w4_inferred_i_1__1]
set_property BEL C6LUT [get_cells u3/w3_inferred_i_1__1]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y227 [get_cells u3/w3_inferred_i_1__1]
set_property BEL D5LUT [get_cells u3/w2_inferred_i_1__1]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y227 [get_cells u3/w2_inferred_i_1__1]
set_property BEL A5LUT [get_cells u3/w1_inferred_i_1__1]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y228 [get_cells u3/w1_inferred_i_1__1]
set_property BEL B6LUT [get_cells u2/w15_inferred_i_1__0]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y228 [get_cells u2/w15_inferred_i_1__0]
set_property BEL C6LUT [get_cells u2/w13_inferred_i_1__0]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y228 [get_cells u2/w13_inferred_i_1__0]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u2/w12_inferred_i_1__0]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y228 [get_cells u2/w12_inferred_i_1__0]
set_property BEL A6LUT [get_cells u2/w11_inferred_i_1__0]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y229 [get_cells u2/w11_inferred_i_1__0]
set_property BEL B6LUT [get_cells u2/w10_inferred_i_1__0]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y229 [get_cells u2/w10_inferred_i_1__0]
set_property BEL C6LUT [get_cells u2/w9_inferred_i_1__0]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y229 [get_cells u2/w9_inferred_i_1__0]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u2/w8_inferred_i_1__0]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y229 [get_cells u2/w8_inferred_i_1__0]
set_property BEL A6LUT [get_cells u2/w7_inferred_i_1__0]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y230 [get_cells u2/w7_inferred_i_1__0]
set_property BEL B6LUT [get_cells u2/w6_inferred_i_1__0]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y230 [get_cells u2/w6_inferred_i_1__0]
set_property BEL C6LUT [get_cells u2/w5_inferred_i_1__0]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y230 [get_cells u2/w5_inferred_i_1__0]
set_property BEL D5LUT [get_cells u2/w3_inferred_i_1__0]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y230 [get_cells u2/w3_inferred_i_1__0]
set_property BEL A5LUT [get_cells u2/w4_inferred_i_1__0]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y231 [get_cells u2/w4_inferred_i_1__0]
set_property BEL B6LUT [get_cells u2/w2_inferred_i_1__0]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y231 [get_cells u2/w2_inferred_i_1__0]
set_property BEL C6LUT [get_cells u2/w1_inferred_i_1__0]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y231 [get_cells u2/w1_inferred_i_1__0]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u1/w15_inferred_i_1]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y231 [get_cells u1/w15_inferred_i_1]
set_property BEL A6LUT [get_cells u1/w13_inferred_i_1]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y232 [get_cells u1/w13_inferred_i_1]
set_property BEL B6LUT [get_cells u1/w12_inferred_i_1]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y232 [get_cells u1/w12_inferred_i_1]
set_property BEL C6LUT [get_cells u1/w11_inferred_i_1]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y232 [get_cells u1/w11_inferred_i_1]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u1/w10_inferred_i_1]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y232 [get_cells u1/w10_inferred_i_1]
set_property BEL A6LUT [get_cells u1/w9_inferred_i_1]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y233 [get_cells u1/w9_inferred_i_1]
set_property BEL B6LUT [get_cells u1/w8_inferred_i_1]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y233 [get_cells u1/w8_inferred_i_1]
set_property BEL C6LUT [get_cells u1/w7_inferred_i_1]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y233 [get_cells u1/w7_inferred_i_1]
set_property BEL D6LUT [get_cells u1/w6_inferred_i_1]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y233 [get_cells u1/w6_inferred_i_1]
set_property BEL A6LUT [get_cells u1/w5_inferred_i_1]
set_property LOC SLICE_X13Y234 [get_cells u1/w5_inferred_i_1]
set_property BEL B6LUT [get_cells u1/w4_inferred_i_1]
```

---

When I placed them, I didn't put one over the other. I am confused where I have caused the physical conflict. Could someone please help me solve this problem. Is there any way how I can easily make changes to adjust the positions and avoid conflict, as I am not sure how the placement should be done to avoid this problem.

My professor wants me to place them in such a way to create a square shape, so that we can later place a Dual port ram around the various sides of the square (made using 20 ROs).

Comment: Riokomoo - Hi, FYI your link [1] is missing.

Comment: @SamGibson here is the link - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hJ1LaSKYYow. Sorry i missed the link.

Comment: Riokomoo - Hi, I see that you posted this question already on the [Xilinx forum](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Implementation/Handling-bel-constraint-conflict-critical-warning/td-p/1250137), with a bit more info (& more images) at the end, and a working link near the beginning. It might help readers *here* if you [Edit] this question, to add the extra information which you included *there*. Or did you reach the maximum question size here? Thanks.

Comment: @SamGibson, yes i actually reached the maximum question size here.

Comment: Riokomoo - Thanks for confirming my guess. I don't have a fix for that :-( At least any interested users here can follow the link in my comment above, to see the extra info you could fit into the question on the Xilinx forum.

Comment: The Xilinx forum link which SamGibson gave now appears to be dead (following re-organisation of the Xilinx forum?). Link now appears to be [Handling bel constraint conflict critical warning](https://support.xilinx.com/s/question/0D52E00006hpQtbSAE/handling-bel-constraint-conflict-critical-warning?language=en_US)